# Use of unresolved identifier 'advance'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've just started learning swift and there one is issue that I cannot resolve.

```
 subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
    return self[advance(self.startIndex, i)]
}
```

and Xcode says "'advance' is unavaiable: call the 'advancedBy(n) method on the index"

So ok I did try to make it using advanceBy but in this case Xcode says:
"Use of unresolved identifier 'advanceBy'"

This first line with advance worked on someone else's Xcode so I'm wondering - what could want wrong? Am I missing something in the project?

I've checked that word advance is in swift 1.2 and this is the version which I'm using.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code compiles with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4). Most probably, you are actually using Xcode 7 GM with Swift 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 2.0 `advancedBy`is a method of `Index`. Seems you need:

```
subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
    return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
}
```